# Alamofire uploading large files with progress and show progress on app restart

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have setup the project with following steps.

1. I had enable External accessory communication and Background Fetch
2. AppDelegate:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        API.sharedInstance.backgroundCompletionHandler = completionHandler
    }
```

3. And here is the API.swift class which im handling all the api calls

```swift
public class API: NSObject {

    var sessionManager: SessionManager
    var delegate: SessionDelegate
    public var backgroundSessionManager: Alamofire.SessionManager

    var backgroundCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)? {
        get {
            return backgroundSessionManager.backgroundCompletionHandler
        }
        set {
            backgroundSessionManager.backgroundCompletionHandler = newValue
        }
    }

    /// access a shared instance of an API manager
    public class var sharedInstance: API {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = API()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    public required override init() {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        self.sessionManager = SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
        let identifier = "com.appname.backgroundtransfer"
        self.backgroundSessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: identifier))
        self.sessionManager.adapter = AccessTokenAdapter()
        delegate = self.backgroundSessionManager.delegate
    }

    func authHeaderWithToken() -> [String : String] {
        return [Constants.HeaderKeys.Authorization : "Bearer " + (AppManager.sharedInstance.accessToken ?? "")]
    }

    func uploadFilesToServer(parameters: [String : Any], image: UIImage?, audio: Data?, video: Data?, uploadItem: Upload, progressHandle: @escaping ProgressHandler, success: @escaping SuccessJsonClosure, failed: @escaping NetworkError) {
        let URL = Constants.BASE_URL + "api_uploadFiles"

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            Constants.HeaderKeys.Authorization : "Bearer " + (AppManager.sharedInstance.accessToken ?? ""),
            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        ]

        self.backgroundSessionManager.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartData) in
            // multipart setup
            if let img = image {
                multipartData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0)!, withName: "file", fileName: "\(uploadItem.fileName!)", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }

            if let vid = video {
                multipartData.append(vid, withName: "file", fileName: "\(uploadItem.fileName!)", mimeType: "video/mov")
            }

            if let aud = audio {
                multipartData.append(aud, withName: "file", fileName: "\(uploadItem.fileName!)", mimeType: "audio/mov")
            }

            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!, withName: key)
            }


        }, to: URL, method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            // transmission closure
            switch (encodingResult) {
            // encodingResult success
            case .success(let request, let streamingFromDisk, let streamFileURL):

                // upload progress closure
                request.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("upload progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                    progressHandle(progress)
                })

                // response handler
                request.responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let jsonData):
                        // do any parsing on your request's response if needed
                        let json = try! JSON(data: response.data!)
                        let isOK = json["success"].boolValue
                        if isOK {
                            success(true, json)
                        } else {
                            failed(nil, json)
                        }

                    case .failure(let error):
                        failed(error, nil)
                    }
                })

            // encodingResult failure
            case .failure(let error):
                failed(error, nil)

            } // end encodingresult switch
        })

    }  
}
```

Files get uploaded successfully to server if the app is not killed. but if i kill the app in middle of uploading, i can't get the progress status. And completion block not get executed when app is restart (kill and open). uploadFilesToServer function get call multiple times (Ex: 5 videos uploading with 5 calls). I need to track the progress for each uploading when the app restarted. How can we track the ongoing request? and how we can upload the large files and run a completion call for each request.

In here im saving the videos to documents directory and pass the Data with url

Answer (score 1):

To run an action on completion you need to override the session's delegate sessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession: ((URLSession) -> Void)? 
[Alamofire doc](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#session-delegate)

For the progress of each upload, I'm still trying to find a way to reattach the delegate, but without success so far.
We must be doing something wrong